# How to use ajax data-table in drupal module?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am creating a module with crud functionality . I used a table view to show database record which only have pagination . The pagination is working with url  and refreshing the page every time to show new result. I want to use ajax data table with sorting functionality . Someone please suggess me links to complete it. .

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to build anything with CRUD functionality in drupal you probably want to use the entity api. 
This integrates perfectly with view wich allows you to use the default pager/ajax.

http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api

Otherwise you'll have to add the 'use-ajax' class to the link and give the hook_menu implementation of the link a 'ajax' delivery callback and have it return a valid array of ajax commands.

See this tutorial for more information

https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/make-link-use-ajax-drupal-7-its-easy